# subset one list on another

Tags: r, list, subset

I have been looking at `mapply` documentation but I cannot find an example close enough to help me get started.

I have lists `foo` and `bar`:

```
set.seed(123)
f   <- data.frame(y=1:10,x=sample(LETTERS,10))
foo <- list(f,f)
b   <- data.frame(x=c("J","U","A"))
ba  <- data.frame(x=c("J","W"))
bar <- list(b,ba)
```

I can subset `f` with `b` using:

```
result <- f[f$x %in% b$x ,]
```

I want to do this subset but for the whole lists `foo` and `bar` i.e. subset `foo[[1]]` by `foo[[1]]["x"]` on `bar[[1]]` and `foo[[2]]` by `foo[[2]]["x"]` on `bar[[2]]` etc...

the result would be:

```
>foo
[[1]]
    y x
3   3 J
4   4 U
6   6 A

[[2]]
    y x
3   3 J
5   5 W
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like so...?

```
mapply(merge,foo,bar,SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
[[1]]
  x y
1 A 6
2 J 3
3 U 4

[[2]]
  x y
1 J 3
2 W 5
```

Comment: reduce things to a problem you have already solved right?..facepalm

Comment: @user1320502 :) Learning has occurred.